# How to find the Text value on the basis of ID using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

NET MVC and i am unable to find the correct option. Please help me in this. I really appreciate. Actually I want to get the Text value using JQuery. And I am using the below code.

```
 function CreateOrUpdate() {
        var modal = $("#purchaseModal");
        var form = $('form[name="purchaseForm"]');

        let tableData = $('#detailsTable > tbody > tr');
        console.log(tableData);

        var tableDto = [];

        $.each(tableData, function (rindex, row) {
            console.log(row);
            debugger;
            let tmp = {};
            tmp.pid = $(row).find('td:nth-child(1)').attr('pid');
            tmp.productName = $(row).find('td:nth-child(1)').text();
            tmp.qty = $(row).find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
            tmp.price = $(row).find('td:nth-child(3)').text();
            tmp.amount = $(row).find('td:nth-child(4)').text();
            tableDto.push(tmp);
            tmp = {};
        });
```

I am getting the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj96r.png). I want Product Name="Register". Please help me in this.

Comment: You can use regex to remove the white space from the string.

Comment: Can you tell me how to use that . Just give one example.

Comment: You can use `trim()` method as well:
`tmp.productName = $(row).find('td:nth-child(1)').text().trim();`

Comment: To make things simple, you can use this. We are using a simple regex replace. ```$(row).find('td:nth-child(1)').text().replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '').trim();``` This will give you just 'Register' as value

Comment: Thank you so much it is working. I really appreciate your help!!!!!!

Comment: @SaiGummaluri & @AnkurPrakash, `trim()` will take care of removing the CR-LF in the beginning and end of the string, there is no need to use `replace` unless you are interested in removing CR-LF in between the string value.